# ignoring white space and tabs in java

Tags: java, filereader

Im getting an error message when trying to ignore a tab between 2 numbers the error appears as follows: In the text file im reading from there are some single digit number and some double digits which is why i am using .substring(42,44);

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5    "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at readTheFile.setSenID(readTheFile.java:230)
    at Sensor.setSensorID(Sensor.java:69)
    at getDrink.<init>(getDrink.java:22)
    at controlPanel$1.actionPerformed(controlPanel.java:54)
```

I have tried several replace white space and tab options such as temp.replaceAll("//t","") or ("\s+",""). I cant seem to find a way to get just the int to read. Any ideas?

heres the piece of code i think is causing the problem

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


            int lineNumber = 0;

            ArrayList<Integer> SenID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                lineNumber++;
                if (lineNumber >= 24) {
                    String temp = line.substring(42, 44);
                    temp.replaceAll("//s+", "");    //think error is here
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                    SenID.add(x);                         
                        }
                    }
```

here is the file im reading from

```
25-Feb-2008 00:20:14    25-Feb-2008 00:22:57    24  1
25-Feb-2008 09:33:41    25-Feb-2008 09:33:42    24  1
25-Feb-2008 09:33:47    25-Feb-2008 17:21:12    24  1
25-Feb-2008 09:36:43    25-Feb-2008 09:37:04    5   1
25-Feb-2008 09:37:20    25-Feb-2008 09:37:23    6   1
25-Feb-2008 09:37:51    25-Feb-2008 09:37:52    14  1
25-Feb-2008 09:37:55    25-Feb-2008 09:37:56    14  1
25-Feb-2008 09:37:58    25-Feb-2008 09:38:01    6   1
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
temp.replaceAll("//s+", "");
```

should be

```
temp = temp.replaceAll("//s+", "");
```

Strings are immutable, so methods such as `replaceAll()`, `trim()` etc. will return a new string rather than modify the existing one.